# Foreach with reference causing array's last element to repeat

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I ran into a weird issue and could reproduce it with this snippet:

```
<?php

$arr = [];

for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $arr[] = [
        $i
    ];
}

foreach ($arr as &$item) {
    $item[] = $item[0];
}

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

It is outputting (notice the last element had been replaced with a copy of its previous one):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
)
```

However, here's the expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
)
```

If I use `array_map` instead of the first `foreach`, it works:

```
<?php

$arr = [];

for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $arr[] = [
        $i
    ];
}

$arr = array_map(function ($item) {
    $item[] = $item[0];
    return $item;
}, $arr);

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

Tested under PHP 8.0.0.

What could be causing this difference? Is there something about array pointers I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, the `$item` variable still holds a *reference* to the last value of the `$arr` when the loop is done.

```
foreach ($arr as &$item) {
    $item[] = $item[0];
}
```

If you use `print_r(get_defined_vars());` you can see that there is a key in the array with name `item`

The behaviour of the double value at the end of the foreach is [described here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and It is recommended to destroy the specified variables using `unset($item)`

You can also use a different variable name.

---

Using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), the callback gets a function argument passed by name, which is bound to the function scope.

If you run `print_r(get_defined_vars());` after using array_map you can see that there is no key named `item`

Comment: Interesting... indeed using a different variable name other than `$item` at the second foreach removes the ending dupe... The first foreach's final iteration marks `$item` as a reference to the array's last item, and the second foreach statement reassigns it over and over (since it is a reference, reassigns the referenced value), causing the last item to be lost... did I understand correctly?

Comment: Nvm... there's indeed a huge red box warning about exactly the behavior I faced on the linked docs. Coding while affected by covid has its drawbacks... Thank you for all responses!

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [];

for($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $arr[] = [
        $i
    ];
} 
/** Output 
* $arr = [[0],[1],[2],[3]]
*/
```

In this foreach loop you are just selecting the existing value of item and setting it into a new index of referenced item

```
foreach ($arr as &$item) {
    $item[] = $item[0];
}
```

Type of $item is array, $item[0] is referred to its 0 index
$item[] means a new array index inside item that is currently referenced to.

Comment: This is intentional. I just didn't understand why the last element was `[2,2]` instead of `[3,3]`...